# C# GridViewRowInfo throws exception but DataGridViewRow works when I convert checkbox column value to boolean.

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, radgridview

This code works

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
               bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
               if (isSelected)
               {
                   dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[3].Value);
               }
           }
           dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

but this doesn't work and gives exception
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in pGridView.Rows)

```
   {
       bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["s"].Value);

       if (isSelected)
       {
           dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[3].Value);
       }
   }
   sGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Exception is given at this line

```
bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["s"].Value);
```

This is exception

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Ricardo
  StackTrace:
       at Ricardo.Books.radButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Suleman\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Ricardo\Ricardo\POS.cs:line 308
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonBase.buttonElement_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonElement.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DoClick(EventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DoMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.CallDoMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentInputBehavior.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Ricardo.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Suleman\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Ricardo\Ricardo\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

How to solve?

What I have tried:

Tried to extend win form gridview class with rad grid view but doesn't work.

Comment: The exception is says there is NO cell with column "s". Did you check that?

Comment: Yes i checked that as I stated it works with builtin gridview.

Comment: If other Gridview is working then make sure both refers to same data source and check whether you are binding correct data source to new grid view. Please debug and check what data you are trying to bind.